# How to retain Firefox cache using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am having a small problem with my selenium automation script running on firefox. Every time I restart the container, I need to authenticate again. On chrome, I was able to use the cache, but not on Firefox. I did search for how to force firefox to use the cache, but or I am missing some step, or the answer was now outdated.

This is the piece of the code that "starts firefox":

```py
def start_firefox():
    try:
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory = '/tmp/firefox')
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,
                                   service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
        return driver
    except Exception as e:
        set_status('selenium', False)
        logging.exception(e)
```

Any idea on what is preventing firefox from reuse the same cache?

**UPDATE**
I tried to run firefox with "--profile /tmp/firefox" (need to import selenium.webdriver.firefox.options) hoping it would reuse the cache, but it just open firefox as it was first-run and it closes a few seconds latter.

```py
def start_firefox():
    try:
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--profile /tmp/firefox')
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(service_log_path=os.path.devnull,
                                   options=options)
        return driver
    except Exception as e:
        set_status('selenium', False)
        logging.exception(e)
```

Still trying random things to see if I can keep my cache like I can on chrome with `options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=chrome-data')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read in one answer that someone had a similar issue and using `webdriver_manager` was able to solve it. I would link it here, but I lost and could not find it.

```py
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

####
####

def start_firefox():
    try:
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--profile')
        options.add_argument('/tmp/firefox/')
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(service_log_path=os.path.devnull,
                                   executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(),
                                   firefox_options=options)
        return driver
    except Exception as e:
        set_status('selenium', False)
        logging.exception(e)
```